# Computing confidence interval of clustered data

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, cluster-sample

*Hi, this is the first time I am posting a question here so I apologize if my questions are not written in the proper manner and corrections will be welcomed*.

I have a dataset in which each instance is defined by a cluster (C) and two more fields: trials and successes forming the following instance vector {C,trials,successes}. I am trying to estimate the confidence interval of $80\%$ for $\hat{p}=\frac{successes}{trials}$ given that different clusters have different homogeneity of variance and a certain unknown $\hat{p'}$ (the instances are not distributed normally, but more like Exponential distribution most of the time). For example, there can be two instances both with $\frac{successes}{trials}=\frac{5}{200}$   but as they come from different clusters their confidence interval can be very different.

I would like to combine somehow the Wilson score interval with the cluster real measured values that form $80\%$ interval (maybe for all instances with enough trails - not sure what should be the threshold at the moment) and get the expected confidence interval.

I would be happy to receive ideas or references about how it can be done (any other ways that can lead to integrated confidence interval will also be welcomed).

Comment: It seems to me that this question is about `clustered sample` and not about `clustering`. Please check you tags.